# Can't get logs from Laravel in Docker with Nginx Unit

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx-unit

I have simple project on Laravel, which is hosted on ECS using  Nginx Unit baked in Docker. The only logs I get are from nginx unit:

```
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [notice] 55#55 module: php 8.2.16 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/php.unit.so"
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [info] 1#1 controller started
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [notice] 1#1 process 55 exited with code 0
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [info] 57#57 router started
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [info] 57#57 OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023, 1010117f
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [info] 58#58 "laravel" prototype started
2024/03/28 14:41:10 [info] 59#59 "laravel" application started
```

And it's quiet after that, no more errors/issues etc.

I've tried different LOG_CHANNEL s as doc is saying: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/logging, but nothing works.

Meanwhile loading same application using `sail` and `artisan` give me logs:

```
app-1      |    WARN  local.ERROR: Application is ready (error log) .  
app-1      | 
app-1      |    WARN  local.INFO: Application is ready (info log) .  
app-1      | 
app-1      |    WARN  local.ERROR: Application is ready (error log) .  
app-1      | 
app-1      |    WARN  local.INFO: Application is ready (info log) .  
app-1      |
```